# Acentos y eñes con funcion copy() PHP

Tags: php

estoy viendo que los ficheros que contienen acentos o eñes se copian mal.

> copy("../hola.txt", "../patá.txt2")

La salida es:

> patÃ¡.txt2

He mirado la configuración del fichero php lo tengo en utf8.

¿Sabeis si puede ser por el servidor apache?

Lo he intentado modificar con:

`AddDefaultCharset utf-8`

Fuente: [SO Ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-apache)

No me funciona, ¿alguien ha tenido un problema similar?

Comment: prueba esto... copy(utf8_decode("../hola.txt", "../patá.txt2"))

Comment: @Alberto Rojas nada eso ya lo he probado

Answer (score 1):

Te paso una función que normaliza una cadena, se puede usar para url's o nombres de archivo.

```
   public function cadenaAUrl($cadena){

        $cadena = preg_replace('/[().,]+/',' ',$cadena);
        $cadena=trim($cadena);
        $originales = array(
            '/À/','/Á/', '/Â/', '/Ã/', '/Ä/', '/Å/', '/Æ/', '/Ç/','/È/', '/É/', '/Ê/','/a©/',
            '/Ë/','/Ì/','/Í/', '/Î/', '/Ï/','/Ð/', '/Ñ/', '/Ò/', '/Ó/', '/Ô/', '/Õ/','/a³/',
            '/Ö/', '/Ø/', '/Ù/', '/Ú/', '/Û/', '/Ü/','/ÝÞ/', '/ß/', '/à/', '/á/','/â/',
            '/ã/', '/ä/','/å/','/æ/','/ç/','/è/','/é/','/ê/','/ë/','/ì/','/í/','/î/',
            '/ï/','/ð/','/ò/','/ó/','/ô/','/õ/','/ö/','/ø/','/ù/','/ú/','/û/',
            '/ý/','/ýþ/','/ÿŔ/','/ŕ/','/---/', '/--/','/,/','/[.]/','/&#8211;/','/–/' ,'/ /',
            '@/@','@__+@', '/-/','/__/','/__/','/ñ/','/\?/','/¿/','/#/'

            );
        $reemplazo = array(
            'a','a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c','e','e','e','e',
            'e','i','i', 'i', 'i','d', 'n','o','o','o','o','o',
            'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u','y','b','a','a','a',
            'a','a','a','a','c','e','e','e','e','i','i','i',
            'i','d','o','o','o','o','o','o','u','u','u',
            'y','yb','yR','r','-','-','-','-',',',',','_',
            '_','_','_','_','_','n','_','_','_'
            );

        $cadena = preg_replace( $originales, $reemplazo, $cadena);
//        $cadena = self::cleanString($cadena);
        $cadena = strtolower(html_entity_decode($cadena));
        return $cadena;
    }
```

Para usarla:

```
$nombreArchivo = cadenaAUrl('patá.txt');
```

Espero te sirva. 
Saludos.

Comment: gracias por la aportacion, pero esa funcion no me sirve ya que quiero poder escribir ficheros con acentos

Comment: @nachfren checa este post; http://xaviesteve.com/354/acentos-y-enes-aparecen-mal-a%C2%B1-en-php-con-mysql-utf-8-iso-8859-1/

Comment: lo he probado y no me escribe eñes ni acentos, al final he decidido sustituir los caracteres